# Объединение строк в C#

Tags: c#

Как из массива строк получить одну строку?

Было:

```
string[] many = { "ab", "bc", "cd", "de" };
```

Стало:

```
string one = "abbccdde";
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Метод [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.join.aspx) сцепляет элементы указанного массива или элементы коллекции, помещая между ними заданный разделитель.

```
string one = string.Join(null, many);
```

Answer (score 11):

Для этого существует специальный метод [String.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.concat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string[] many = { "ab", "bc", "cd", "de" };
string one = string.Concat(many);
```

Некоторые перегрузки метода `Concat` используют внутри себя [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), например метод принимающий `IEnumerable<T> values`. Другие перегрузки используют внутри себя [небезопасный код](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t2yzs44b.aspx), например метод принимающий `params String[] values`. Все это должно давать хорошую производительность при конкатенации строк.

Answer (score 5):

Еще можно используя [StringBuilder.Append](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b4sc8ca8(v=vs.110).aspx), к примеру:

```
string[] many = { "ab", "bc", "cd", "de" };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
many.ForEach(x => sb.Append(x));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result: " + sb)); // Result: abbccdde
```

Доступные методы слияния строк:

1. Сложение строк с использованием символа `(+)`
2. [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. [string.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx)
5. [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Ответ можно дополнить дополнительными способами, если таковые имеются.

Comment: а как в данном случае помогает string.Format? применительно к массиву

Comment: @Grundy, `string.Format` - преобразует значения объектов в строки на основе указанных форматов и вставляет их в другую строку. Соответственно его можно использовать либо в методе, который преобразует массив в строку, перебирая элементы, либо в Lambda-запросе. Я привел доступные в моем понимании методы слияния строк, даже типичное преобразование. Результатом  будет строка

Comment: все равно не понятно как String.Format можно использовать для слияния строк в массиве

Comment: @Grundy, вот пример: `string resultPlus = string.Empty;
            many.ForEach(x =>  resultPlus = string.Format("{0}{1}", resultPlus, x) );`

Comment: ох,ох,ох.......

Comment: @Grundy, да, я понимаю, что способ не самый лучший, но все же - тоже способ. Так сказать особый случай "жесткого" кода.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43675/discussion-between-grundy-and-denis-bubnov).

Comment: А зачем `many.ForEach(x => sb.Append(x));`? Чем это лучше `foreach (var x in many) sb.Append(x);`?

Comment: @VladD, запись в одну строку, а не в две

Comment: @DenisBubnov: (1) А что мешает записать в одну строку? (2) А чем две строки хуже? Количество символов примерно то же самое, а конструкция проще, понятнее и эффективнее (нету косвенного вызова через лямбду).

Comment: @VladD, я привык пользоваться лямбдами. На мой взгляд такой код получается минимальным и содержательным. Собственно говоря - код понятен. Сколько программистов - столько мнений. Есть множество вариантов написания кода, выполняющего одну задачу.

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Я тоже привык пользоваться лямбдами. Но по моему мнению, в данном контексте лямбда не нужна, раз можно обойтись нативной конструкцией. Лямбды нужны, чтобы сделать код проще, а не чтобы сделать его использующим лямбды.

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Может быть, мнение Эрика Липперта вас убедит: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: @VladD, да, убедили. По поводу проще, а не использующим лямбды. Просто для меня показалось проще, когда кода меньше. Да, Эрик затронул отладку - труднее отлаживать. Но я объяснил свое видение. Спасибо за интересную статью.

Answer (score 2):

Самый банальный наверно способ:

```
string[] many = { "ab", "bc", "cd", "de" };
string one = "";

for (int i = 0; i < many.Length; i++)
{
    one += many[i];
}
```

Comment: При этом последовательно создаются строки `ab`, `abbc`, `abbccd`, `abbccdde`. Далеко не самый оптимальный способ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вообще говоря исключения не будет, но да, множественное создание строк при их большом количестве может стать проблемой

Comment: -1: Майкрософт специально предостерегает от этого способа, так как он квадратичен по количеству копирований и создаёт много временных строк. Если уж непременно хотите вручную, нужно использовать `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @VladD, тут уже был ручной StringBuilder, но его почему-то тоже заминусовали :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Ручной `StringBuilder` — это просто практически бесполезный код, раз в библиотеке есть лучшая функция. Но он хоть эффективен. Не стоит плюса, как рекомендующий неоптимальный подход, но не стоит на мой взгляд и минуса.

Comment: @VladD, а что может быть оптимальнее цикла со StringBuilder, библиотечные же функции его же и используют

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43672/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).